# Softlayer API -- how to check whether my order is accepted or not

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I placed a order to upgrade a virtual machine's hardware by api(python) "placeOrder", it returned successfully. And I used "wait_for_transaction"(function in VSManager) to wait this transaction to be finished. After a few minutes, it also returned successfully. However, when I login the website "control.softlayer.com", I found the upgrading ticket showed that it had been cancelled with saying that "XXXX is unable to be completed due to insuffcient resources in the datacenter pool. The upgrade request has been cancelled and this ticket has been closed".

So how could I check this order has been accepted and handled successfully? I need to know the order result.

Answer (score 2):

The "wait_for_transaction" function in VSManager only checks if the transaction status is not pending, that's why the result is successful despite a failed transaction.
To verify if the upgrade has effectively worked, is necessary to review the status of the last transaction.

You could review the next example script using the python client:

```
"""
Retrieve a computing instance's associated upgrade request object if any.

Important manual pages:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeRequest
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Upgrade_Request
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

virtualGuestId = 12345678

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME,
                          api_key=API_KEY)

virtualGuestService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']

objectMask = 'mask[completedFlag,order,status,ticket[title,id],virtualGuest[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,lastTransaction[transactionGroup]]]'

try:
  upgradeRequest = virtualGuestService.getUpgradeRequest(mask=objectMask, id=virtualGuestId)
  # The result should display the upgrade request status, order status, ticket associated
  # and the last transaction and transaction status of the current Virtual Guest.
  # Note: The upgrade request status could be the next:
  # APPROVED
  # PENDING
  # PENDING_CUSTOMER_APPROVAL
  # COMPLETE
  # CANCELLED
  # MAINTENANCE_UPDATE_REQUIRED
  # IN_TRANSACTION
  # PENDING_PAYMENT_PROCESS
  # PENDING_AUTOMATED_FINALIZE
  pp(upgradeRequest)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
  pp('Unable to upgrade the VSI faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
     % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```